# AFX_DIRECTORYCHANGES_H__02E53FDE_CB22_4176_B6D7_DA3675D9F1A6__INCLUDED_

Tags: c++

I can't find the mean of this line in the Net. What does this means in C++, please ?

```
#if !defined(AFX_DIRECTORYCHANGES_H__02E53FDE_CB22_4176_B6D7_DA3675D9F1A6__INCLUDED_)
    #define AFX_DIRECTORYCHANGES_H__02E53FDE_CB22_4176_B6D7_DA3675D9F1A6__INCLUDED_

    // code... code... code...

#endif // !defined(AFX_DIRECTORYCHANGES_H__02E53FDE_CB22_4176_B6D7_DA3675D9F1A6__INCLUDED_)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's some generated [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: @bereal, what does double inclusion means please ?

Comment: That's right there in the article. When you, directly or not, include the same header multiple times, the compilation may fail because of the same types being defined multiple times.